# utility native to OS X for administering AD accounts (without "magic triangle")

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, ldap, opendirectory, osx-snow-leopard

EDIT: So far I have explored

1. Centrify Suite (Spoke with a rep who didnt believe they offered a solution for this)
2. Thursby ADmitMac (I have seen evidence that a tool exsists, but I'm failing to find a way to obtain/purchase, or verify that it is still current/operational with said environment)
3. Apache Directory Studio (among other LDAP browsers)

   - I admit ignorance in how LDAP/AD accounts work, but I dont believe the user account password can be reset from this method anyways? I do find the accounts via filtering search sAMAccountType=805306368 though.

EDIT:This machine is in the correct container in the AD tree. A solution not requiring a local VM would be ideal.

This is in a Server 2003 Environment. The the account has Domain/Enterprise Admin permissions. I am trying to come up with a way to administer AD accounts (reset pw's, flag for pw change etc.) without having to RDP to a Windows box to utilize the Admin Pack.

For background information, the client machine I would like to run this from is running OS X 10.6 and is properly bound to the domain and single sign on works perfectly - I have tried (out of desperation) to use Workgroup Manager for this purpose. Workgroup manager will retrieve the account's and they can be viewed, but it will not allow you to attempt to authenticate (the lock in the upper right hand corner is grayed out). Additionally, when attempting to make any changes, permission is denied.

There is no Open Directory server, and making real schema changes is probably out of the question due to the hoops I'd have to jump through in order to make it happen.

Is there a native OS X utility to assist with this? Is there an Open Source project that can facilitate this, that I can run on an intranet web server?

I'm positive this comes down to an inadequacy in knowledge of the integration specifics, but I'm having a hard time figuring out/finding a cut and dry answer to this.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, the solution I have come up with is called [Corendal Directory Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/corendaldiry/).

It is an OSS web-based AD administration tool. It wont be a native client, but it will certainly be more convenient than having to RDP in to another box, or running a VM just to utilize the Admin Pack.

I'm sure there are other solutions out there, and I am extremely interested to know of them if anyone has any input.

This has the potential to be useful beyond the scope of my original intrest as well. It may be the same for others...

Answer (score 1):

Also check out ADHelpdesk.  It does what you want from your iphone or ipad, the developer says there is a desktop version in the works: http://adhelpdesk.com/